# How to parse content with <pre>?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am using jsoup to parse a number of things.

I am trying to parse this tag

```
<pre>HEllo Worl<pre>
```

But just cant get it to work.

How would i parse this using jsoup?\

```
    Document jsDoc = null;
     jsDoc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
 Elements titleElements = jsDoc.getElementsByTag("pre");
```

Here is what i have so far.

Comment: Of course **Jsoup** will do it. Post relevant code so we can help.

Comment: Did you mean to have two opening `pre` tags and no closing tag?

Comment: It was missing the ending </pre> tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me with latest Jsoup:

```
String html = "<p>lorem ipsum</p><pre>Hello World</pre><p>dolor sit amet</p>";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements pres = document.select("pre");

for (Element pre : pres) {
    System.out.println(pre.text());
}
```

Result:

> Hello World

If you get nothing, then the HTML which you're parsing simply doesn't contain any `<pre>` element. Check it yourself by

```
System.out.println(document.html());
```

Perhaps the URL is wrong. Perhaps there's some JavaScript which alters the HTML DOM with new elements (Jsoup doesn't interpret nor execute JS). Perhaps the site expects a real browser instead of a bot (change the user agent then). Perhaps the site requires a login (you'd need to maintain cookies). Who knows. You can figure this all out with a real webbrowser like Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: I just want to extract the Hello World text

Comment: Why didn't you said that in your question? Just call `text()` method on `Element`. I updated the answer.